# intensity of point process - weights with covariate - spatstat

Tags: spatstat

I am trying spatstat for a specific case. In my shapefile of roads, i have attributes speed and % of heavy vehicles on each road. It is an observation that severe accidents are likely to happen on roads with high speeds and more heavy vehicles (because road is  not properly access controlled and pedestrians cross the road). We know that there are accidents at a rate (per 5km stretch).

1. I would like to generate a random poisson with that rate, but giving weight that the points happen more on roads with high speed ( or high % truck)
2. and if possible also to include the second variable % of trucks

What is the best way to model the two aspects to make a small proof of concept? I have read (portions of) the spatstat book and section on influence of covariates on intensity, but this is still unclear to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spatstat` function `rpoislpp` generates a Poisson random point pattern on the network with a given intensity. In this case, you want a spatially-varying intensity, which can be specified by a function of spatial location. That is, you want something like `rpoislpp(f, L)` where `L` is the linear network and `f` is the intensity function.

I assume you have obtained values of the covariate (like speed limit and fraction of trucks) for each road. Then you need to build a function that looks up these values at any spatial location on the network. Once you have this, you can write the intensity function in terms of it.

To start, suppose you have a network `L` (object of class `linnet`). The segments of the network can be indexed in the original order given when you specified them: or you can extract these segments by `S <- as.psp(L)`. We need a vector `z` giving the covariate values for each of these segments (so this will be a numeric vector of length `n=nsegments(S)`). Then `z[i]` is the covariate value along segment `i`. (Note: if you have covariate values for each *road*, where a road consists of multiple segments of `L`, then you first need to figure out which segments of `L` belong to each road, and construct `z`.)

Next do the following:

```
Zfun <- linfun(function(x,y,seg,tp) { z[seg] }, L)
```

This creates a function on the linear network (class `linfun`) that evaluates the covariate at any spatial location on `L`. To check it's built correctly, type `plot(Zfun)`.

Now suppose you want the point process intensity to be `lambda = exp(3*Z+2)`. Then do

```
lam <- function(x,y,seg,tp) { exp(3 * z[seg] + 2) }
lambda <- linfun(lam, L)
```

(Needless to say, you can write any mathematical expression in the braces; and you can have more than one covariate, etc.)

Finally generate the random points:

```
X <- rpoislpp(lambda, L)
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like to request more clarification please. When you say, the function looks up these covariate values at any spatial locaiton > do you mean, it looks at each seg for z? So when the algorithm reaches a `seg` it will look for this function? For example, in the example you mention, if i have lambda = z, that means a poisson rate of z is applied to each segment? How the function is applied to the network is not clear to me. And it is also not clear if the function also depends on length of the segment.

Comment: To cite from the book pg720 - " intensity is the expected number of points per unit length of network in vicinity of u." I do not understand that. What is the vicinity ? is it the covariate z of seg ? it is not clear to me.. Thank you again for your patience.